# How to check value of drop down list without jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, button, dropdown

I want to make a function that, when the button is pressed, checks what option is selected from each drop down list. Don't know how i would do this and everything i find online is jquery, something i don't want to use. It might not be possible, which would be fine cause i could just use imput values insted but figured i might aswell ask here fisrt.

```
<body>
    <select class="Alder" name="Alder">
      <option id="B">0-12år</option>
      <option id="V">Eldre en 12år</option>
    </select>
    <select class="Dager" name="Dager">
      <option id="1">1 Dag</option>
      <option id="2">2 Dager</option>
      <option id="3">3 Dager</option>
      <option id="4">4 Dager</option>
      <option id="5">5 Dager</option>
      <option id="6">6 Dager</option>
      <option id="7">7 Dager</option>
    </select>
    <button id="prisKnapp" type="button" name="button">Regn ut pris</button>
  </body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could get value form all dropdown input by assigning class on each select input, let say you are using `select` class name.

html :

```
<body>
    <select class="Alder select" name="Alder">
    <option id="B">0-12�r</option>
    <option id="V">Eldre en 12�r</option>
    </select>
    <select class="Dager select" name="Dager">
    <option id="1">1 Dag</option>
    <option id="2">2 Dager</option>
    <option id="3">3 Dager</option>
    <option id="4">4 Dager</option>
    <option id="5">5 Dager</option>
    <option id="6">6 Dager</option>
    <option id="7">7 Dager</option>
    </select>
    <button id="prisKnapp" type="button" onclick='getVal()' name="button">Regn ut pris</button>
</body>
```

javascript :

```
var sel = document.getElementsByClassName("select");

function getVal(){
    for (const key in sel) {
        if (sel.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            console.log(sel[key].value);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `option`s `value`s instead of `id`s, and you can then use the [`FormData` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) to serialize the form as if it were submitted "traditionally" and access the values that would be sent:

```js
document.getElementById("f").addEventListener("submit", (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  const fd = new FormData(event.target);
  alert(
    'Dager: ' + fd.get('Dager') + '\n' + 
    'Alder: ' + fd.get('Alder')
  );
});
```

```html
<body>
  <form id="f">
    <select class="Alder" name="Alder">
      <option value="B">0-12år</option>
      <option value="V">Eldre en 12år</option>
    </select>
    <select class="Dager" name="Dager">
      <option value="1">1 Dag</option>
      <option value="2">2 Dager</option>
      <option value="3">3 Dager</option>
      <option value="4">4 Dager</option>
      <option value="5">5 Dager</option>
      <option value="6">6 Dager</option>
      <option value="7">7 Dager</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit" name="button">Regn ut pris</button>
  </form>
</body>
```